# cur.execute(sql,params) sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask, browser

I am currently having a problem with my code. I know that there are many answers to this question on the website, but I tried everything, and I didn't manage to solve the problem.

I am using flask, if that helps.

Here is my code :

````
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)  
    cur = conn.cursor()
    IdClub=determiner_id_club(nom_club)
    sql= "SELECT idClub FROM Inscription WHERE idClub=? AND idAdherent=?"  
    #Vérifier si l'utilisateur est inscrit dans le club 
    params=(IdClub,idAdherent)
    print(params)
    cur.execute(sql,params)
    verif_club = cur.fetchone()
    return (verif_club) 

@app.route('/create')
def create():
    msg_affiche = ""
    idAdherent=flask.session["idAdherent"]
    nom_club= request.args.get("nom_club")
    date = request.args.get("date")
    heure = request.args.get("heure")
    description = request.args.get("description")

    if verif_club(nom_club,idAdherent) is None : 
        print(verif_club(nom_club,idAdherent))   
        #Si le booléen est Faux
        msg_affiche = "vous n'êtes pas inscrit à ce club"
        return render_template("create_event.html", msg = msg_affiche) 
    else:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db)  
        cur = conn.cursor()
        sql2="INSERT INTO Evenements ('Date','Heure','Description') VALUES (?,?,?,?)" 
        cur.execute(sql2,[date,heure,description])
        sql3="INSERT INTO Organisation idClub=?" #lier cet évenement à un club
        cur.execute(sql2,determiner_id_club(nom_club))
        conn.commit()
        cur.close()
        conn.close()
        msg_affiche="Félicitations ! Vous avez créer un évenement"
    return render_template("create_event.html",msg=msg_affiche) ```


---

I have also tried this :
````

def verif_club(nom_club,idAdherent):
conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
cur = conn.cursor()
IdClub=determiner_id_club(nom_club)
sql= "SELECT idClub FROM Inscription WHERE idClub=? AND idAdherent=?"
#Vérifier si l'utilisateur est inscrit dans le club
cur.execute(sql,[IdClub,idAdherent])
res=cur.fetchone()
return (res)

Comment: What does `determiner_id_club` function do? What is the value of `params` when you get the error message? How does the `Inscription` table look like?

Comment: `determiner_id_club` returns the id of the club that has the name that has been entered in argument.

Comment: I tried to print params, but it doesn't appear in the shell !

Comment: As for the Inscription table, it is composed of idAdherent, idClub, idRole, MontantCotisation,DureeCotisation

Comment: So I guess these fields are numeric ones. So if `determiner_id_club` does not return a number, it can cause this error message. Could you share this function as well?

Comment: Yers of course. I just posted the fonction determiner_id_club, as an answer to my question

Comment: You said that you tried to print `params` but nothing happened. That could mean `IdClub` and `idAdherent` variables are empty causing the SQL error. So you should verify that these variables are valid numbers. You should also implement some sort of error handling, so when these variables are empty for some reason, then you don't try to make additional SQL queries because they will fail.